# How do I include my own xcconfigs when using Cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8, xcconfig, podfile

Is there a way to specify in the `Podfile` that an `xcconfig` file should be `#include`d in the the one generated by Cocoapods?

Is there an exposed method/variable for appending this `#include` or do I need to read the generated `xcconfig` and regurgitate it with the additional text?

For instance, in the generated `Pods-SomeTarget.[configuration].xcconfig`, I'd like to see:

```
#include "my_other_config.xcconfig" //<-- I want this to be inserted

FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics" "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric" "${PODS_ROOT}/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds-GoogleIMA3ForAdMob" "${PODS_ROOT}/NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent" "${PODS_ROOT}/TwitterCore/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/TwitterKit/iOS"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
```

Comment: What #include do you want to exactly?

Comment: @Larme Added an example.

Comment: You can use `post_install` to do that in your podfile: (a colleague did that in one of our project) `post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| target.build_configurations.each do |config| xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path puts xcconfig_path xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path) common_xcconfig = '#include "my_other_config.xcconfig"' File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << common_xcconfig file.puts file << xcconfig } end end end`

Answer (score 7):

Include these lines in your debug and release xcconfig files, respectively:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Used/Pods-Used.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Used/Pods-Used.release.xcconfig"
```

Then click on your project and in the detail navigation bar on the left switch from your current target to your project and select Info at the top.  Set the project to use your base/shared config file and Debug/Release to point to your xcconfig files.

Comment: Any tips on how to make this work when there are multiple targets? Pods-Used is just one specific target. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHodge Cocoapods should generate a separate config file for each target, in addition to each build configuration. So for two targets and two build configurations you should have 4 config files.